# What can actually trigger the Active status of a systemd target unit, such as suspend.target?

Tags: 22.04, systemd

I'm having [a server that apparently randomly goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434435/dell-server-is-no-more-accessible-after-entering-sleep-state-kernel-pm-suspen) and I cannot figure out what actually *triggers* that state in the system logs.

Hence my question: what process(es) or event(s) are able to actually trigger the status of the following `systemd` target into an `active` state (e.g. putting the system into sleep) on Ubuntu 22.04?

```
$ systemctl status suspend.target 
○ suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
systemctl enable suspend.target
```

Mind that `enable` will error out if the system service has faults and it will show this:

```
$ systemctl enable suspend.target 
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

If so to enable it ... that issue needs to be fixed 1st.

Comment: ...which is basically the case for all suspend/sleep/hibernate targets, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see is that the power saving triggers it. Upon reading through the `man systemd.special` you can see that the `suspend.target` pulls in the `sleep.target` and will be called upon when it is needed.

```
   suspend.target
       A special target unit for suspending the system. This pulls in
       sleep.target.
   sleep.target
       A special target unit that is pulled in by suspend.target,
       hibernate.target and hybrid-sleep.target and may be used to hook
       units into the sleep state logic.
```

It is part of the `Special System Units` that is managed by the system service manager.

Running `systemctl start systemd-suspend.service` will put your system right to sleep as it is now active, so it has to remain inactive until it is needed.

Comment: Hmm, so there should be something which trigger or call that `systemd.special` on my server recently, but I cannot figure out why/what. I'll study it more deeply, hopefully I will understand what happens. Because for me, these states make sense on a personal computer, but they should not be triggered on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I also met with the same case:

```
systemctl status systemd-suspend
● systemd-suspend.service - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd-suspend.service(8)
```

Luckily when I was browsing this page, I had a thought.

Use `journalctl -b -1 -u systemd-*` to check:

```
10月 20 15:05:36 HOSTNAME systemd-logind[830]: Suspend key pressed.
10月 20 15:05:36 HOSTNAME systemd-logind[830]: Suspend key pressed.
10月 20 15:05:38 HOSTNAME systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
10月 20 15:05:38 HOSTNAME systemd-sleep[442813]: Suspending system...
```

What does `Suspend key pressed` mean?

Press the power key on the keyboard.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-5233/z400162db17/index.html

Conclusion:
You may have pushed the suspend key on your keyboard by accident.
It will suspend your server even if you disabled the suspend service.
Press the power button can bring it back. And it's the only way to bring it back except for rebooting.